# VB6 error 424 (Object Required) at object calling line

Tags: vb6

I get error 424 (Object Required) when I try to run these codes on VB6 module:

> Public wsIRC As Winsock
>
> Function START()
>
> wsIRC.Connect THEHOST, THEPORT
>
> End Function

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new Winsock object like this

`set wsIRC = new Winsock`

You may also need to specify
`Public withevents wsIRC As Winsock`

Comment: Now I get "Invalid use of new keyword".

Comment: hmmm, been a long time since I used vb6.  is the winsock an *.ocx on a form?

Comment: Yes. but I don't want to use forms. I just want to make a module so I can use it in any project and it does not depend on the winsock on the form, if I could fix it!

Comment: You will probably need to use a class module instead of a module